# TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make an event where if the message content equals the given condition then it does something however it keeps showing me this error

TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message, user:discord.User ):
        if message.content.lower() == f"<@{user.id}> beat <@{user.id}>":
            await message.send("It works!")
```

Comment: You cannot add more arguments to events, delete the last `user` argument

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, you cannot add more arguments to events, it's not a command

```py
async def on_message(self, message):
```

To get the `user` variable you can use the `Message.author` variable

```py
user = message.author
```